# Why am i getting a huge number for the int sum in this code?

Tags: c

so i am writing a code that lets the user inputs as much numbers as he want but when he inputs -1, the loop stops and the sum of the numbers  that he has input before -1 is printed as well as for their average. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int x, counter = 0, sum = 0;
float average;

printf("Input any number: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

while(x != -1){
sum =+ x;
counter++;
printf("Input any number: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
}
average = 1.0*(sum/counter);
printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", &sum, &average);

return 0;
}
```

The problem is that i am getting a weird result of the sum. Here's the result that im getting when i put 5 then 5 then -1 as input:

Input any number: 5

Input any number: 5

Input any number: -1

sum is 6356764 and average is 0.00

What is the problem ? any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: Read your compiler warning output.

Comment: Don't use `&` on arguments to `printf` (unless you're using `%p` to print an address).

Comment: Don't "fix" the code in your question, it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: I suspect you likely want `average = 1.0*sum/counter;`, else code is doing integer division.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes it was doing an integer division. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your compiler you will probably get some extremely helpful feedback from its warnings:

```
compiler.cpp: In function 'int main()':
compiler.cpp:17:59: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int*' [-Wformat=]
 printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", &sum, &average);
                                             ~~~~          ^
compiler.cpp:17:59: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'float*' [-Wformat=]
```

It's ofc trying to tell us to change this:

```
printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", &sum, &average);
```

into this:

```
printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", sum, average);
```

Additionally you have a small typo here:

```
sum =+ x;
```

as it should obviously be:

```
sum += x;
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason it prints that value of `sum` is that

```
printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", &sum, &average);
```

takes wrong arguments as `%d` and `%f` - `&sum` and `&average` are adresses of variables `sum` and `average` instead of their values. Compile your code with `-Wformat` flag and you will get the warning:

```
main.c:17:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]                                                                     
main.c:17:39: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
```

Simply change that line to

```
 printf("\nsum is %d and average is %.2f\n", sum, average);
```

and everything will work fine.